# Alternative for abstract static method in Dart

Tags: dart, design-patterns, static

I need something like an abstract static method, but since we cannot do something like this in the dart, so I am looking for alternatives, my situation is like this:-

Firstly classes:-

```dart
abstract class Parent {
  static String get name;
  static Parent fromSecretText(String name);
}

class ChildFirst {
  static String get name => 'first_child'; //note:- here it is not the typename
  static ChildFirst fromSecretText(String name) { 
    // generate object 
  }
}

class ChildSecond {
  static String get name => 'second_child';
  static ChildSecond fromSecretText(String name) { 
    // generate object 
  }
}
```

Now I need methods like this:-

```dart
Future<List<T>> getMultiple<T extends Parent>() async {
  final List<String> secretKeys = await getSecretKeys(T.name);
  List<T> res = [];
  for (var secretKey in secretKeys) res.add(T.fromSecretText(secretKey));
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in Dart.

Static members of a class declaration are just that: Methods on the *declaration*, which is treated like a namespace for lookups.

Static members are unrelated to the *type* that the class introduces. That's even more obvious when the class is generic, because then the class declaration introduces multiple types, one for each generic instantiation, but the static methods don't know anything about that.

A type parameter, like `<T extends Parent>` here, abstracts over the *type*.
There is no way to access static methods from the type, you need the actual name of the declaration.

What you can do is to have the classes be represented by strategy objects.

```dart
abstract class SecretStrategy<T> {
  String get name;
  T fromSecretText(String name);
}
/// Maybe implemented like
class _SecretStrategy<T> implements SecretStrategy<T> {
  final String name;
  final T Function(String name) _fromSecretText;
  _SecretStrategy(this.name, this._fromSecretText);
  T fromSecretText(String name) => _fromSecretText(name);
}
```

Then your classes can define their own strategies:

```dart
class Person {
  static final SecretStrategy<Person> secretStrategy = 
      _SecretStrategy<Person>(name, fromSecretText);
  ...
}
class ChildFirst {
  static final SecretStrategy<ChildFirst> secretStrategy = 
      _SecretStrategy<ChildFirst>(name, fromSecretText);
  ...
}
// etc
```

and your helper function would then be:

```dart
Future<List<T>> getMultiple<T>(SecretStrategy<T> strategy) async {
  final List<String> secretKeys = await getSecretKeys(strategy.name);
  return [for (var key in secretKeys) strategy.fromSecretText(key)];
}
```

which you can call as:

```dart
var result = await getMultiple(FirstChild.secretStrategy);
```